# Как отследить, что пользователь заблокировал мой Telegram бот?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Я хотел бы узнать, как можно отследить, что пользователь заблокировал мой Telegram бот. Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы удалять из базы данных пользователей, которые выходят из моего бота в Telegram.

Сейчас у меня реализован следующий обработчик события для бота, который, как я думал, должен срабатывать, когда пользователь удаляет бота из чата:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=[types.ContentType.LEFT_CHAT_MEMBER])
async def left_chat_member(message: types.Message):
    # Удаление из базы
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    print(f"Пользователь {user_id} удалил бота из чата.")
```

Однако, когда я тестировал это, обработчик не сработал, и база данных оставалась неизменной. Может быть, я делаю что-то не так?

Буду благодарен за любые советы или подсказки, как правильно отслеживать, когда пользователь заблокировал мой бот в Telegram и каким образом я могу удалить его из базы данных.

Заранее спасибо за вашу помощь!

Answer (score 0):

В Telegram API нет прямого способа узнать, что пользователь заблокировал вашего бота.

Но можно периодически отправлять сообщения пользователям и следить за статусом их доставки. Если сообщение не доставляется, это может быть признаком того, что пользователь заблокировал вашего бота. Но недоставка сообщения также может быть связана с другими проблемами, такими как ошибка в телефонном номере пользователя или временными проблемами с сетью. Поэтому этот метод не является абсолютно надежным.

Также можно записывать в бд дейтвия пользователя. Например вы можете записывать, когда пользователь последний раз отправлял команды вашему боту. Если пользователь не проявляет активность в течение определенного периода времени, то возможно что пользователь заблокирон Бота. но это тоже не сто процентый вариант, так как пользователь может просто ничего не писать в бота при этом его не блокируя

Comment: совершенно не верный ответ

при отправке сообщений, телега шлет ответ, и если будет написано "bot was blocked by the user" Значит юзер заблокировал бота. Нет ни каких номеров телефона и проблем с сетью, если что то не так с сетью то сообщение придет пользователю позже, но бот его успешно отправит. Бот отправляет сообщения по id юзера а не по номеру телефона.

Comment: записывать время последней команды тоже не верный вариант, он может сегодня был и заблочил. Написал свой верный ответ

Answer (score 0):

Бот  в скрипт шлет сообщение в момент когда юзер блокирует/разблокирует бота, ловить их надо так:

```
@dp.my_chat_member_handler()
async def my_chat_member_handler(message: types.ChatMemberUpdated):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.new_chat_member.status == "kicked":
            # сохраняем в базу что юзер заблочил бота
        elif tmessageg.new_chat_member.status == "member":
            # сохраняем в базу что юзер разблочил бота
```

и сохранять статус юзера в бот. Далее ты в базе можешь увидеть кто заблочил а кто нет

Если ты хочешь так проверить юзеров которые ранее у тебя в базе, к сожалению такого способа нет. Отправь рассылку на всех, и лови ответы. "bot was blocked by the user" - означает что юзер заблочил бота. и можешь после отправки сообщения сразу удалять.